# How can I say about these two compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**My problem:**

Suppose $E \subset [0,1]$ and $C \subset [0,1]$ are two compact sets such that $E \subsetneq C$ and $\mathop C\limits^ \circ
=\mathop E\limits^ \circ
=\emptyset$ and $|E|=|C|=0$.

Can I say that there exist $0 \leq a<b \leq 1$ such that $]a,b[ \subset [0,1]-C$ and $\{a,b\} \cap C-E \neq \emptyset$?

**My attempt:**

I tried writing $C^c$ as an opportune union of connected components, but I cannot reach any conclusion.

Comment: I think that you have a quantifier problem here: it should probably be "there exists $t_0$ such that for all $t$, blah blah if $t<t_0$ and blah blah otherwise".

Comment: I understand you are looking for $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$ so that $]a,b[ \subset [0,1]-C$ and $\{ a, b\} \cap C-E\neq \emptyset$. Does this rephrase your question?

Comment: @FormulaWriter Yes you are right, this rephrase my question and it looks better.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I meant $\exists t$ and $\exists t_0$. Maybe FormulaWriter's comment is clearly stated.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini Ok, then I think it is better that you edit your question accordingly, for as it is currently stated it does not look so clear.

Comment: @FormulaWriter I edited the question as you remarked.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Pick a point $x\in C-E $.
$E$ is closed, therefore you can find $r>0$ so that $(x-r, x+r)\cap E = \emptyset$. Now look for suitable $a,b \in (x-r, x+r)\cap [0,1]$.

EDIT: adding further details.

Suppose $x\neq 1$ and define $A:=(x,x+r)$.

If $A\cap C = \emptyset$, a possible solution is $a=x,$ $b= \min\{x+r,1\}$.

Suppose now $y \in A\cap C$. The interval $(x,y)$ cannot be a subset of $C$, because $\mathop C\limits^ \circ = \emptyset$. For this reason, there exists $ z\in (x,y) - C$. You can now choose $(a,b)$ as the connected component of $z$ in $C^c$.

If $x=1$, you can look at $B:=(x-r,x)$ instead of $A$ and exploit the same idea.

Comment: It may be syntaxically correct but it is still weirdly stated.

Comment: The question can be reworded better, nevertheless what is asked is quite clear I think.

Comment: In my experience, when the question seems a bit odd, more often than not a couple of well-intended people try their best still answering it until the OP realizes that they did not really mean what they have asked.

Comment: Ok, I see your point.

Comment: @FormulaWriter I did not undestand the case $A \cap C = \emptyset$. Could you please explain it clearer?

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini I edited the answer to make it clearer, let me know if you have any doubts left